# $Ax + By = C$ where $A, B, C$ are positive whole numbers. Is it possible to have an infinite number of solutions to this?

Tags: number-theory

$Ax + By = C$ where $A, B, C$ are positive whole numbers. Is it possible to have an infinite number of solutions to this or will it have a specific number of solutions or just a single solution? (solutions being positive whole numbers too, i.e. both $x$ and $y$ should be positive whole numbers too.)

Comment: What do you think yourself? Hint: just assume $A = B = 1$ and think about it

Comment: Obviously it is finite - don't understand the rest of the question.

Comment: $0 < x < \frac CA$, $0 < y < \frac CB$, ...

Comment: @ronald putting A=B=1 gives x+y=C where neither x nor y can be negative,will have an more than one solution but not infinite. that's what i think.

Comment: Correct, since all numbers are positive by requirement, you'll have a finite number of solutions for $x$ and $y$. And depending on $A$ and $B$ there will be more or less solutions (e.g. if $A>C$ you'll have no solutions at all).
For me this approach to assume some simple values and to look how the equation behaves is a way to learn to understand the question. And from there it'll be a small step to find the solution Martin R posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no solution (e.g. $x+y=1$), exactly one solution (e.g. $x+y=2$),
or multiple solutions (e.g. $x + y = 3$).

In any case, the number of solutions is finite, since
$0 < x < \frac CA$ and  $0 < y < \frac CB$.

Answer (score 1):

Since all numbers are positive, we have
$$1\le x,y <Ax+By,\quad\text{hence}\quad 1\le x,y\le C-1,$$
so there can't be more than $(C-1)^2$ solutions.

Comment: could you please show me how did you come up with that limit??

Comment: @Malik: Just order the solutions you've found yourself while assuming $A = B = 1$ in a square and count the number of entries.

Comment: Well, both $Ax$ and $By$ are $\ge 1$, and since their sum is $C$, each has to be $\le C-1)$. Note however this is not an optimal bound – it's only the simplest to obtain.

Comment: @Ronald And Bernard, Understood. Am i correct to assume that the actual number of solutions will be dependent on the values of A and B?

Comment: Just imagine $A$ and $B$ are even (e.g. 2) and $C$ is odd. It won't be hard to count all solutions, even if $C$ is incredibly large. And as I pointed out before, if either $A>C$ or $B>C$ you also won't find any solutions. So yes, the number of solutions definitely depends on the values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Note that, given $A,B,C$, there's an algorithm to obtain a base solution, which uses the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*, and a formula to obtain all other solutions in signed  integers.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B\neq0$ any $x$ there is at most one $y$ that satisfies $Ax+By=C$.

Also for $x$ large enough we have $Ax>C$ so that $Ax+\text{ any positive number}>C$

Since $x$ is demanded to positive we conclude that there are only a finite number of $x$'s  for wich there is an $y$ that satisfies $Ax+By=C$.